# Ionic Capacitor One-To-One Chat Notification

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, chat, capacitor

Here's the thing:

---

I've made an one-to-one private chat with ionic capacitor, saving messages in Cloud Firestore. By far it's working fine. Both users can send and recieve messages.
On the other hand, I've made push notification with FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging) according to official document of capacitor(https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase) and from console of Firebase I can publish notificationes to certain device as I've got their tokens.

---

So, can I implement message notification using FCM as well when a user recieve a new message? Just like whatsapp, wechat o others common chat apps.

Attention: I'm using Ionic **Capacitor** + Angular. **NOT cordova**.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have to do is whenever you get the token , save it in your database with the user_id or device_id, then when sending message to a recipient, you get the token of the recipient from database(eg: get token where user_id=recipient_id) then send notification to that token.